# How to bind nested list item in listview

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to do databidning for a list and under the list, there is another nested list.
Here is my model:

```
public class ChecklistSection
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ChecklistCategory ChecklistCategory { get; set; }
    public List<ChecklistItem> ChecklistItems { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:xxx.xx.xxx.App.ViewModels"
             x:Class="xx.xx.xxx.App.Views.Checklist"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:ChecklistViewModel">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ChecklistSections}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ChecklistCategory.Name}" />
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ChecklistItems}">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <StackLayout>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is my viewmodel:

```
public class ChecklistViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<ChecklistSection> _checklistSections;
    public ObservableCollection<ChecklistSection> ChecklistSections
    {
        get => _checklistSections;
        set
        {
            if (_checklistSections != value)
            {
                _checklistSections = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ChecklistSections));
            }
        }
    }
```

The xaml file can recognize the ChecklistSections, but it can't recognize ChecklistCategory, ChecklistItems and itemname. I only defined ChecklistSections in the viewmodel. The app doesn't depoly and give me this error:

XFC0045 Binding: Property "ChecklistCategory" not found on "xx.xx.xx.App.ViewModels.ChecklistViewModel".

Comment: you need to define `DataType` properties on the two `DataTemplate` nodes

Comment: @Jason, sorry I didn't understand. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify a `DataType` for each `DataTemplate`.

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:ChecklistSection">
```

and

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:ChecklistItem">
```

this allows the XAML compiler to determine what the correct `BindingContext` to use for the `Binding` properties

Comment: with your solution, I need to define all the fields in the ViewModel, but Instead of this, I only want to define the checklistsection, and all the other fields are under it. The list is coming from the API  and it's dynamic

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  You need to add two attributes to your XAML, that's it.

Comment: *"The list is coming from the API and it's dynamic"* - If you've tried what Jason said, and it doesn't do what you need, then add more info at the end of your question. Show code updated to do what he says, and show text of error message you get.